# Flask / UWSGI architecture with worker thread

Tags: flask, uwsgi, debian-based

Following code approximates real code. Flask app on starts creates a worker thread. Routing function use data processing done by worker function .

```
app = Flask(__name__)

timeStr=""

def loop ():
        global timeStr
        while  True:
                time.sleep (2)
                timeStr =datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
                print (timeStr)


ThreadID = Thread (target=loop)
ThreadID.daemon = True
ThreadID.start()

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return   os.name + " " + platform.platform() + " " + timeStr

application=app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The above app works beautifully for days when started likes this:

```
python3 app.py
```

However in uwsgi, even though I have enabled threads, app is not working. It's not updating global timeStr

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --wsgi-file /home/pi/pyTest/app.py   --http :80 --touch-reload /home/pi/pyTest/app.py  --enable-threads --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

What do I need to do for app to function correctly under UWSGI, so I have create systemd service proper way?

Comment: What is it you're seeing (or not seeing) that suggests that timeStr isn't getting updated?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith - timeStr is alway empty, means it was not updated from initial “” value

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, good news.

I have an app that starts a worker thread in much the same way. It uses a `queue.Queue` to let routes pass work on the worker thread. The app has been running happily on my home intranet (on a Rapsberry Pi) using the Flask development server. I tried putting my app behind `uwsgi`, and observed the same failure -- the worker thread didn't appear to get scheduled. The thread reported as `_is_alive = True`, but I couldn't find a `uwsgi` switch combination that let it actually run.

Using `gunicorn` resolved the issue.

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3
. venv/bin/activate
pip install flask gunicorn
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 demo:app
```

was enough to get my app to work (meaning the worker thread actually ran, and side-effects were noticeable).

Comment: Thank for you for the suggestion. I did try Gunicorn. However I ran into timeout issues (widely reported without solution if you search for “gunicorn timeout”. ) For some unknown reason worker process times out and dies. This of course deletes my in memory structure. I am puzzled how such simple architecture is so difficult to reliably implement with either gunocrn or uwsgi

Comment: We have apps in production at work using both gunicorn and uwsgi, and haven't noticed timeout issues (but then we're using `celery` as a job queue).

Comment: Tried again, and for no reason Gunicorn worker times out and exists. Of course it takes all my in-memory data, as I rely on the worker process not to exit. While I can re-write app to not rely on the worker process to just continually run, I just don't get  why it exits.

Jul 10 15:19:20 raspberryVM gunicorn[10941]: [2020-07-10 15:19:20 -0700] [10941] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10944)
Jul 10 15:19:20 raspberryVM gunicorn[10941]: [2020-07-10 15:19:20 -0700] [10944] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10944)